# Simple HTML DOM help

Tags: php, html, dom, simple-html-dom

How can I extract the value attribute of an input tag? Using **SIMPLE HTML DOM**
let me give you an example:

```
<form action="#" method="post" name="test_form" id="test_form">
Name<input type="text" name="name" value="NaMe"/><br />

Address<input type="text" name="address" value="AdDrEsS"/><br />

<input type="hidden" value="sayantest" />
</form>
```

I want to extract just the value of hidden type input tag, not the others.

Comment: What language are you using to access the DOM?  Javascript?

Comment: Are you talking about this PHP library? http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: David: Seems to be, yes. tagged

Answer (score 4):

You want to put the id (so you can access the value in javascript), as well as a name (if you want to access the value on the server) in the tag you wish to get the value from.

e.g.

```
<input type="hidden" name="test" id="test" value="sayantest" />
```

then your javascript is as simple as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var val = document.getElementById('test').value;
  alert(val);
</script>
```

Comment: +1 You can also consider making use of the jQuery library and accessing your elements using that.  If you do use jQuery, your code may look something like this $('#test').val();

Comment: Check out more basics at: 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp

Answer (score 3):

> using SIMPLE HTML DOM

Do you mean the PHP library of that name?

If so, you'd have to choose a way to identify the input. If you can't change the markup to add an `id` or `name` on the hidden input you want, you'd have to come up with something like “get the first input with type hidden in the form”:

```
$html= new simple_html_dom();
$html->load('<html><body<form action="#" method="post" name="test_form" id="test_form">Name<input type="text" name="name" value="NaMe"/><br />Address<input type="text" name="address" value="AdDrEsS"/><br /><input type="hidden" value="sayantest" /></form></body></html>');

$input= $html->find('#test_form input[type=hidden]', 0);
$input->value;
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, as already mentioned, is to give your hidden input an `id` attribute and then use `getElementById` and then `.value` or `.getAttribute('value')` to select it.

Alternatively, if you want to get the values of all hidden inputs on the page, or can't inject your ID, you could use something like this:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
    if(inputs[i].getAttribute('type') == 'hidden'){
        alert(inputs[i].getAttribute('value'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with... using exactly what you showed in your initial question. Note that all I did was `echo` the value of all input hidden, where `test_form.htm` is your original:

```
<?php
function scraping_form()
{
   // create HTML DOM
   $html = file_get_html('test_form.htm');

   // get input hidden value
   $aObj = $html->find('input[type="hidden"]');
   foreach ($aObj as $hKey=>$hidden)
   {
     $valueAttribute = $hidden->value;
     echo "*TEST* ".$hKey.": ".$valueAttribute."<br />";
   }

   // clean up memory
   $html->clear();
   unset($html);

   return;
}
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// test it!
// user_agent header...
ini_set('user_agent', 'My-Application/2.5');
scraping_form();
?>
```